# Is ”Physical”'s IPA spelling not unique?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, vowels, ipa

Could you come up with an explanation why the same adjective "physical" has two IPA renderings of the same pronunciation?

[Oxford Learners Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/physical_1?q=physical): /ˈfɪzɪkl/ (that is the **/ə/** is missed in spelling, but heard):

The rest of English dictionaries: /ˈfi-zi-kəl/

Physical - [LDOCE](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/physical)

Is there something particular here, or just a typographical error?
P.S. I have checked *logical*, the same difference in "spelling” of the pronunciation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different dictionaries use different symbols to transcribe the same sound. So you'll see different transcriptions such as:

- /ˈfɪzɪkəl/
- /ˈfɪzɪkl/
- /ˈfɪzɪkl̩/
- /ˈfɪzɪk<sup>ə</sup>l/
- /ˈfɪzɪk(ə)l/

The last syllable is unstressed and has an obstruent (/t p k s z/ etc) followed by a sonorant (/l m n/ etc). When an obstruent is followed by a Sonorant in the same unstressed syllable, the sonorant is usually [syllabic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/266963/106592) (i.e. it forms a syllable on its own).

The same thing happens in the last syllable of *physical*. The /l/ is syllabic and the air is [released laterally](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/266963/106592), so some dictionaries transcribe it /ˈfɪzɪkl/ or /ˈfɪzɪkl̩/. Most people, however, pronounce it with an intervening vowel, so some dictionaries transcribe it with a vowel: /ˈfɪzɪk**ə**l/.

Other examples are:

- bottle → /ˈbɒtəl/ or /ˈbɒtl̩//
- button → /ˈbʌtn̩/ or /ˈbʌtən/
- prism →/ˈprɪzəm/ or /ˈprɪzm̩/
- *-ism* → /-ɪzəm/ or /-ɪzm̩/

(In the last three words, the air is [released nasally](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/273341/106592).)

Both the transcriptions are correct. Also note that dictionaries are often inconsistent with their use of IPA.

Answer (score 0):

Both pronunciations are correct.  ˈfi-zi-kəl' is used when speaking slowly. In normal pace, it is usually ˈfi-zi-kl'. There are no errors.

Comment: Its not because of the speed of speech .... I can pronounce it either way regardless of the speed of my speech